# Storing app preferences in Spring app

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm working in a Spring MVC application that needs access to some variables that the admin user must set using a web wizard (smtp server, preferences, etc). I want to store this info in a database to be accessible by the app. Which is the best way to store this info?

Comment: What exactly do you want to ask: how to store values in a database, or how to read sprong properties (@value) from a database, or...?

Comment: @Ralph Sorry. I'm asking about how people define their entities (sql schema) to have app preferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use an approach with default values and a generic GUI. Therefore we use a property file that contains the default value as well as type information for every key. in the dayabdatabase we store only this values that have been modified by the user. The database schema is just a simple key value table. The key is the same like the one from the property file, the value is of type string, because we have to parse the default value anyway. The type info (int, positiveInt, boolean, string, text, html) from the propty file is used by the generic GUI to have the right input for every key.

Example:

default.properties

```
my.example.value=1
my.example.type=into
```

default.properties_en

```
my.example.title=Example Value
my.example.descruption=This is..
```

Db:
Key=string(256)
Value=string(2048)

Answer (score 2):

Please spend some time with [Section IV of Spring Reference Manual](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/spring-data-tier.html). There are plenty data persistence option supported by Spring. To name few popular ones: JDBC, JPA, Hibernate, XML

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Spring-Data, JPA and Hibernate. My question is about how to store this information at a table level (schema).

Comment: Typically you have to model your db table as a Java entity object, decorate it with few annotation, and setup JPA based DAO (Data Access Object) classes. Plase have a look and study the manual